# Не работает рабочий стол Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, gnome

[image: os version]
[image]
[image]

Компьютер завис и после перезагрузки отказывается загружать рабочий стол.
startx работает только от sudo и очень ограниченно. Не очень хотелось бы переустанавливать всю систему, возможно это можно починить? Подскажите какой лог посмотреть или как переустановить рабочий стол полностью, как проверить не видеокарта ли это сгорела?

UPD: Я выяснил что не работает именно gnome, как его можно переустановить?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 1):

Решение найдено! В моем случае не работали один или несколько расширений gnome-shell. После удаления папки с рашрениями загрузка рабочего стола прошла в штатном режиме.
Для удаления необходимо:

1. Перейти в дополнительное рабочее окружение `ctrl+alt+F2`
2. Ввести логин пароль
3. Перенести или удалить папку с расширениями `sudo mv ~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions/ ~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions_old/`